# Delayed_job locking but not processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue with delayed_job.  For some reason I see lots of jobs locked_by and locked_at but nothing being processed out of the queue.  Any tips to why this could be happening or how to get it to move on?

I'm using Rails 2.3.11 and Ruby 1.9.2p0

Thanks!

Comment: hi, what errors do you get when running the jobs using the command "rake jobs:work"

Comment: Unfortunately the jobs are being ran via a Daemon so I can't or haven't been able to run as a rake task.  For some reason when I start/stop the daemon some emails will go out, but then stop.  Its a mess...

Comment: Hi - when I start this via rake I get no errors:


>> Delayed::Worker.new.start
[Worker(host:apps pid:26284)] Starting job worker

The rake method of starting does the same as the daemon - just locks up rows and sits - nothing is being put out.

Curious where to look internally to clear this behavior up.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have had the exact same problem for some time and I'm forced to manually reprocess! the photos in order to correct the issue. Or restart delayed_jobs

Answer (score 8):

When delayed job is forcefully terminated (which happens when you deploy a new version to production using capistrano), the currently processing jobs which are locked will stay locked. You can manually clear the lock by setting `locked_at` and `locked_by` to null.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on how to clear the DJ's lock?

Comment: @BogdanPopa for the record in question, update the updated_at and locked_by column to null