# Delayed Job on Heroku gets locked on app push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

I have a delayed job that will be running infinitely on a worker dyno on Heroku.

Now, every time I make changes and push the app to heroku, the job is locked and is not started again by the "new" worker that Heroku assigns.

How can I get around this? Is there a DJ setting that ensure that the job is picked up by the new worker? I don't want to have to manually start all the jobs every time I push to heroku.

**Edit:** The job, specifically, connects to Twitter's realtime API, so when I push changes, the connection to Twitter is lost since the old worker is stopped.

Thanks!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11983818/465082

Comment: Are you pushing a new worker class? So instead of working through `TwitterAPIWorker`, is there a new worker class like `TwitterAPIWorkerV2`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile):

```
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. Placing that in a Procfile simply tells Heroku to start a worker on launch, correct? How do I ensure that a job locked by an old worker is picked up by the new one? Thanks

Comment: Added some details to the original post. They do work off the same backend - its just that the old job is locked to the old worker?